# Reporting a binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, r-squared, reporting

The binary logistic regression model was found to be non-significant for my results.

What should I include in my results section?  For example, would I still report the Nagelkerke $R^2$?

Comment: What is your dependent variable of interest? How many independent variables were in the model? What is the purpose of the model? Who is the audience of the model? What was the R-squared of the model?

Comment: The DV was whether participants responded yes or no to participating in a follow up study. I had 3 predictors (including an interaction term) and the R-squared was .159

Comment: 0.159 is fairly strong, 0.2-0.4 is considered a "good" model, it is not the same as r-squared in OLS/linear regression, where we seek to get as close to 1 as possible. Additionally, it is important to look at the r-squared using the model built on a training set on a hold out sample to evaluate model performance.